# Windows Azure Multi site / Multi domain

Tags: azure

I doing a research, is it possible for an Azure VM to have multi site - multi domain? Will it add cost to my subscription? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provision Azure VM and you pay only for that VM.

You have freedom of setting multiple websites (multiple domains) on that VM and that will not increase your VM cost.

Please bear in mind that currently Azure VM are in *preview* and the price may change once *preview* is over.

I would also recommend following [FAQ](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/licensing-faq/) page which can help you with other questions.